# WordFrequencyData fails

Tags: bugs, curated-data

**Bug introduced in 10.4 and persisting through 11.2.0 or later**

---

WordFrequencyData can take a list of words and return the frequencies for all of them. However, using a list of words from a dictionary (which is one of the major cases I suspect) fails.

```
words = DictionaryLookup[{"German", All}];
freq = WordFrequencyData[words, "Total", Language -> "German"];
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

I was able to download the word-frequencies by accessing chunks of 100 and iterating through all of the 76k words. However, taking a closer look, I believe the underlying text that was used to calculate the word-probabilities is by no means representative for the language.

Look at this for the German words: you, Berlin, and politics

```
WordFrequencyData[#, Language -> "German"] & /@ {"du", "Berlin", "Politik"}

(* {0.000109012, 0.000187439, 0.000108065} *)
```

I hope we can agree, that the word "Berlin" (the German capital) should never be twice as likely as the word "You" in a language. "Politics" is almost as likely as "You" which makes me wonder what text was used to calculate these weird frequencies.

**[CASE:4012382]**

> I do agree that to two issues you pointed out demonstrate potential issues with WordFrequencyData. There does not appear to be any documented restrictions on the size of what you're able to evaluate, and the German examples you sent do look suspicious.
>
> I have forwarded your concerns onto our development team asking that they investigate and look to address issues.

Comment: Any update on this? I experienced the same issue regarding the "Unable to fetch word frequency results" error

Answer (score 2):

According to the [`WordFrequencyData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WordFrequencyData.html) documentation page, "by default, `WordFrequencyData` uses the Google Books English n-gram public dataset."

It does not explicitly say what is used for German, but just for the sake of argument, let's check the Google Books [result](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=du%2CBerlin%2CPolitik&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdu%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CBerlin%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CPolitik%3B%2Cc0) for those words.

[image]

Comment: +1 Good catch, I haven't seen that. Unfortunately, it makes it even more disappointing. "Search a lot of books" is clearly not what happens here. "Search a lot of subjectively selected books" should be the label. I mean, Berlin is just one city. It's not even our capital for very long (28 yrs) compared to Washington DC (218 yrs!) for the US. Nevertheless, the [comparison of "you, Washington, politics, president"](http://i.imgur.com/Lohevm0.png) looks vastly different and like I would expect it.